# firebird how a co-admin user can view other users

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

1. I created a user with "gsec.exe"

   ```
   add manager -admin yes
   ```
2. I connect with manager user, and I created several users, but as I want to view users created with command `disp` I see that the user "manager"

The question is: how to display the users created by co-admin "manager" without connecting with "sysdba"?

Comment: Did you connect with the role `RDB$ADMIN`? A non-SYSDBA user only has admin rights if the role is explicitly specified when connecting.

Comment: I removed the Delphi tag, as your question has absolutely nothing to do with Delphi. Please use only tags that are relevant to the question you're aking; including tags that are irrelevant won't help you get an answer any more quickly.

Comment: yes I add `-role RDB$ADMIN` in connection
but `disp` command does not display the user I created